How can I detect whether a `webviewPanel` is either floating-window or not in vscode?
In vscode's webviewPanel object, we can set ViewColumn so that we can control where the panel goes.
For example, if we set ViewColumn.Beside then the panel goes beside the current active window.
There is also a floating window, that you can move/copy an existing window into floating one by selecting "Move(Copy) into New Window" in the context menu of the window (right click on the window title).
My question is: how can I detect whether a webviewPanel is in floating window or not?
I've investigated with debug console and I found out there are only ViewColumns, and I couldn't find any floating or editor group related membership/functionalty.
I hope I have a member field like webviewPanel.isFloating or have a vscode API like vscode.window.tabGroups.all[2].isFloating so that I can match the panel in question with the specific tabGroups.
